# running commands from files

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, command

Let's say that I write some commands in a file let's say cmake although it doesn't need to be cmake run writing some commands in a text file. example

filename: cmake_command

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo ../prject-src/ && make && make install
```

let's for simplicity say that the cmake_command file is located in a folder where if you run the command as is, things will start building.

I tried this command

```
for i in $(cat cmake_command); do echo $i; done
```

as a test but instead of printing out 1 whole line, it splits on each white space so I get a list of individual strings.

How could I reorganize this command to work so instead of getting

```
cmake 
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo 
../prject-src/ 
&& 
make && make install
```

i'd get this output

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo ../prject-src/ && make && make install
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Are you trying to print the `cmake_command` file line-by-line? If so, what is wrong with just `cat cmake_command`?

Comment: have all command one line at a time, then run `bash -e` command_file, `-e` flag will ensure exit on first error.

Answer (score 1):

The most easy way would be:

```
while read i; do echo "$i"; done < cmake_command
```

Comment: Will this produce output that is different from `cat cmake_command`?